# The program does not use the font

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I installed a font correctly using this code

```
Try
    Dim FontFile As String = "Myriad1.ttf"
    Dim dstPath As String = "C:\Windows\Fonts\"
    File.Copy(FontFile, Path.Combine(dstPath, Path.GetFileName(FontFile)))
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts", "Myriad", "Myriad1.ttf")
```

The font appeared in Visual Studio and I also used it
But when I run the program the font is not used, another font appears

**Edit** :

It appears to have been a bug in Visual Studio
I restarted it and tried to use the font but this message appears

[image]

Comment: [AddFontResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontresourcew) / [RemoveFontResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-removefontresourcew). Notify the change broadcasting  `WM_FONTCHANGE` (with `SendMessage`). You can also add a Font as resource to your app and use the [PrivateFontCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection) class to manage it (TrueType fonts only, but since you tagged this WinForms, that's what you can use).

Comment: just to C++ and #C ?

Comment: VB.Net can PInvoke exactly as C#. The `PrivateFontCollection` is .Net class. You can use that, unless you actually want to install a Font in the System, not just use it.

Comment: Actually I used `PrivateFontCollection` I have a problem with it
When I use `Visible` for any tool, the font type is automatically changed
For example, when the `Visible = False` in `button` and `button` is changed to `True` within the program, the font type will be changed

Comment: For this I try to install the font file

Comment: Can you show how you added that Font using the PrivateFontCollection? Did you use `AddMemoryFont()` and called `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem()` maybe?

Comment: i use this

`Dim font1 As New PrivateFontCollection()`
`font1.AddFontFile("Myriad.ttf")`
`Label1.Font = New Font(font1.Families(0), 13, FontStyle.Regular)`

For example, use `Visible = False` in `Panel`, which is an error message that appears by using `Timer`, when an error appears, all fonts return to their previous form

Comment: Because you have already destroyed your PrivateFontCollection. You're declaring it as a local variable, while you need to preserve it until the Form is closed (or the application terminates), when you dispose of it. So, declare it as a an instance Field (a Field of your Form class) and call `Dispose()` on it in the `Form.FormClosed` event. You can only use TTF Fonts, not OTF or Bitmap fonts.

Comment: I thought it just works like this, lol i didn't know that thank you very much, and sorry for taking much time for this

Comment: I added it in class and it worked thank you

Comment: Remember to Dispose() of this object. It's very important.